# ListPicker not compatible with SilverLight project, I don't have a SilverLight project

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, listpicker, wptoolkit

I have just installed the Windows Phone Toolkit (http://phone.codeplex.com/) with the intention of using the ListPicker.

When I try and add it to the XAML it states that it's not valid for a Silverlight project. However when I started this project I chose Windows Phone, not Silverlight.

Any ideas what may be going wrong?

[image: ListPicker Error]

Comment: Have you added XML Namespace toolkit? `xmlns:toolkit=....`?

Comment: I hadn't, and that solved it, so if you add that as a solution I'll green tick it. They didn't mention that in the tutorial I was reading :/

Comment: I'm glad I've helped. The idea of SO is that your problem was solved. I'm not eager to add one sentence answers - so as for me you could delete your question.

Comment: It's nice to hear that on here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XAML,

you can do like this

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
<toolkit:ListPicker></toolkit:ListPicker>
```